How to use wincnn for a big input matrix?
Input matrix size is 16*11, kernel size is 3*3, stride and padding are 1, how to calculate A, G and B by using wincnn?

What do you mean "how"? How does it work in theory? You tried something and it didn't work and you want to solve those problems? A sample code using any existing library? A sample code using a specific existing library? Check online tutorials and libraries, specify where that's not enough.
